# gbm binary classification in r

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

I was trying to perform binary classification, the response variable is "class" which takes value 0 or 1. But the output of predict function (yhat.boost1) is a continuous variable. How do I make it to binary?

```
set.seed(2016)

seismic1 <- read.csv("seismic.csv")
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

seismic1[,c(4:7,9:13,17:18)] <- seismic1[,c(4:7,9:13,17:18)]
seismic1 <- seismic1[,-(14:16)]

for(i in c(1:3,8)){
  seismic1[,i] <- as.numeric(seismic1[,i])
}

#set training and test data   
n <- dim(seismic1)[1]
p <- dim(seismic1)[2]

set.seed(2016)
test <- sample(n, round(n/4))
train <- (1:n)[-test]
seismic1.train <- seismic1[train,]
seismic1.test <- seismic1[test,]

#perform gbm classification 
?gbm
start.time <- proc.time()
boost.seismic1 =gbm(class~.,data=seismic1.train, distribution="bernoulli",n.trees =5000, interaction.depth =4)
summary(boost.seismic1)


#predict on the test dataset
yhat.boost1=predict (boost.seismic1,newdata =seismic1 [-train,],n.trees =500,type="response")
yhat.boost1
```

Comment: As an answer to my question: I think I should use "round" function to yhat.boost1

Comment: `round(yhat.boost1)` or `ifelse(yhat.boost1>0.5,1,0)`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use cutoff to 0.5

```
 ifelse(yhat.boost1>0.5,1,0)
```

That is if the probability is greater than 50% then it should be one and if its less then 50% then it should be 0